# listView items don't respond to click

Tags: android, listview

i have a listView inserted into a dialog, when i click an item of the list it doens't respond to the action,i have set the listener, but i don't understand why `onItemClickListener` is not called.

```
   public void init() {
        toMeetDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        toMeetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.person_to_meet);
        listOfPersonToFollow = (ListView) toMeetDialog.findViewById(R.id.list_view_to_meet);
        confirmButton = (Button) toMeetDialog.findViewById(R.id.button_to_meet);
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        listOfPersonToFollow.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mapsActivity, R.layout.list_item_to_meet, mapsActivity.getPersonToFollow());
        listOfPersonToFollow.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        toMeetDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(mapsActivity, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

list_item_to_meet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="26dp" />
```

person_to_meet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/persons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/person_to_meet"
        android:textColor="@color/opaque_red" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_to_meet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="138dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_to_meet"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/confirm_to_meet" />

</LinearLayout>
```

what's wrong with this code?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add `.show();` to the end of the `Toast.makeText` line and see if that changes anything

Comment: thanks a lot, well was that, disctraction, disctraction everywhere....

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the complete Activity, have you done something like:
listOfPersonToFollow.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had cases when setting the `OnClickListener` of a button inside a list row has made the `blocksDescendants` futile. After setting the `OnClickListener`, make the button not focusable with `setFocusable(false)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)`.

Try this:

```
public void init() {
        toMeetDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        toMeetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.person_to_meet);
        listOfPersonToFollow = (ListView) toMeetDialog.findViewById(R.id.list_view_to_meet);
        confirmButton = (Button) toMeetDialog.findViewById(R.id.button_to_meet);
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        confirmButton.setFocusable(false);
        confirmButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        listOfPersonToFollow.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mapsActivity, R.layout.list_item_to_meet, mapsActivity.getPersonToFollow());
        listOfPersonToFollow.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        toMeetDialog.show();
    }
```